# Logout from ASP.NET MVC client app and a .NET 5 openiddict server. Post logout redirect url invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, openiddict

I'm using OWIN 4.2 with .NET Framework 4.7.2 for my ASP.NET MVC client app.
Login works completely fine but logout will fail.

On my client's startup.cs

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "MVC",
                ClientSecret = "MVC-Secret",

                Authority = "https://localhost:44305/",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/",
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/"),
                
                Scope = "openid api",

                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookie",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                UseTokenLifetime = false,

                RedeemCode = true,
                SaveTokens = true,

                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query,

                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to the OnAuthenticationFailed method
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            // generate code verifier and code challenge
                            var codeVerifier = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(32);
                            
                            string codeChallenge;
                            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
                            {
                                var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
                                codeChallenge = Base64Url.Encode(challengeBytes);
                            }

                            // set code_challenge parameter on authorization request
                            n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("code_challenge", codeChallenge);
                            n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("code_challenge_method", "S256");

                            // remember code verifier in cookie (adapted from OWIN nonce cookie)
                            // see: https://github.com/scottbrady91/Blog-Example-Classes/blob/master/AspNetFrameworkPkce/ScottBrady91.BlogExampleCode.AspNetPkce/Startup.cs#L85
                            RememberCodeVerifier(n, codeVerifier);
                        }

                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;

                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;
                            }
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = n =>
                    {
                        // get code verifier from cookie
                        // see: https://github.com/scottbrady91/Blog-Example-Classes/blob/master/AspNetFrameworkPkce/ScottBrady91.BlogExampleCode.AspNetPkce/Startup.cs#L102
                        var codeVerifier = RetrieveCodeVerifier(n);

                        // attach code_verifier on token request
                        n.TokenEndpointRequest.SetParameter("code_verifier", codeVerifier);

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;

                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                               id,
                               n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                }
            }
        );
```

I also tried

```
...
                Authority = "https://localhost:44305/",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/signout-callback-oidc",
...
```

And also

```
...
                Authority = "https://localhost:44305/",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44347/",
...
```

However, all these results in the response

> error:invalid_request
> error_description:The specified 'post_logout_redirect_uri' is invalid.
> error_uri:https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2052

On my server, the configuration is as follows

```
await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                DisplayName = displayName,
                RedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:44347/")
                },
                Permissions =
                {
                    ...
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:44347/")
                }

            }, cancellationToken);
        }
```

I have also tried changing Server config to

```
PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:44347/signout-callback-oidc")
                }
```

Comment: Can you check the entry in the database if it corresponds to what you set up? The configuration is stored in OpenIddictApplications in the database

Comment: I have checked the database and can confirm that these values are updated and correct.

Comment: could you share your server and client full `startup`'s? I have to make the same bunch but can't figure that out on the ASP.NET MVC site. btw, did the answer help?

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue, what solved it for me was to add the logout permission in the application - `OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Logout`

```
await _applicationManager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientSecret = "901564A5-E7FE-42CB-B10D-61EF6A8F3654",
    DisplayName = "MVC client application",
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { new Uri("http://localhost:53507/signout-callback-oidc") },
    RedirectUris = { new Uri("http://localhost:53507/signin-oidc") },
    Permissions =
    {
        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
        OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode
    }
});
```

Comment: I find it somewhat disturbing that we have to specify this by hand, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: I was confused by the error message. Should have said permision error or something.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Apps in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69671657/6477254, I can confirm that you must allow permission for the logout endpoint, using the constant value of `OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Logout`, which hold  `"ept:logout"` string value when creating the OpenIddict data.